# Unable to authenticate with LDAP plugin

Tags: plugins, ldap, openshift

I am using LDAP plugin for authentication.

I did below setting inside LDAP plugin file -

AuthLDAPURL  =  ldap://:389/ou=openshift,dc=,dc=,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*).

Commented below lines

## LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so

## LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so

After doing above setting , we are able to start/ restart broker service successfully using command – service openshift-broker restart

But still  we are unable to login with users which are present inside LDAP directory. It is authenticating from htpasswd file which is default one.

Please let us know how can we bypass or remove default authentication with LDAP Auth ?

any help will be really appreciated. Waiting for the response.

Thanks,
Jyoti

Comment: This seems to be either a OpenShift Origin or OpenShift Enterprise issue. If so, go ahead and tag it appropriately.